# POD startup fails : efs.csi.aws.com not found in the list of registered CSI drivers

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-efs

I followed this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/containers/running-stateful-workloads-with-amazon-eks-on-aws-fargate-using-amazon-efs/)  to create persistent volume claim and use it in a pod on AWS fargate.

Here are my configuration files

redis-csi.yaml :

````
kind: CSIDriver
metadata:
  name: efs.csi.aws.com
spec:
  attachRequired: false```

redis-sc.yaml :
```kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: efs-sc
  namespace: $ns
provisioner: efs.csi.aws.com
````

redis-pv.yaml :

```
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: redis-efs-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  csi:
    driver: efs.csi.aws.com
    volumeHandle: $WOF_EFS_FS_ID::$WOF_EFS_AP
```

redis-pvc.yaml :

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: redis-efs-uploads-pvc
  namespace: $ns
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
```

redis-sts.yaml :

```
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: redis-cluster
spec:
  serviceName: redis-cluster
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis-cluster
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis-cluster
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: redis
          image: redis:alpine
          command:
            - redis-server
            - "/redis-master/redis.conf"
          env:
            - name: MASTER
              value: "true"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6379
              name: client
            - containerPort: 16379
              name: gossip
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /redis-master-data
              name: data
            - mountPath: /redis-master
              name: config
      volumes:
        - name: data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: redis-efs-uploads-pvc
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: redis-config-map
            items:
              - key: redis-config
                path: redis.conf
```

and here is a part of my script :

```
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=$ns

kubectl apply -f volume/redis-csi.yaml
( echo "cat <<EOF" ; cat volume/redis-sc.yaml; echo EOF ) | sh | kubectl apply -f -

export WOF_EFS_FS_ID=$WOF_EFS_FS_ID
export WOF_EFS_AP=$WOF_EFS_AP
( echo "cat <<EOF" ; cat volume/redis-pv.yaml; echo EOF ) | sh | kubectl apply -f -

( echo "cat <<EOF" ; cat volume/redis-pvc.yaml; echo EOF ) | sh | kubectl apply -f -
( echo "cat <<EOF" ; cat redis-config-map.yaml; echo EOF ) | sh | kubectl apply -f -
kubectl apply -f redis-sts.yaml
```

**Problem**

When ns = default : everithing is fine and my redis container is up. But when I create an other namespace and set ns=othernamespace, I have the following error with my pod :

```
Warning  FailedMount  91s (x11 over 7m43s)  kubelet            MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "redis-efs-pv" : kubernetes.io/csi: attacher.MountDevice failed to create newCsiDriverClient: driver name efs.csi.aws.com not found in the list of registered CSI drivers
  
Warning  FailedMount  67s (x2 over 3m22s)   kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[data], unattached volumes=[config kube-api-access-t44sq data]: timed out waiting for the condition
```

Every time I delete all and recreate all on default namespace, the pod starts correctly. But when I try to deploy in an other namespace I have the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the configurations you've provided, it seems like you are creating manually the `AWS EFS CSI driver` CSIDriver

I recommend to have a correct behaviour that you install the Amazon EFS CSI driver through the Amazon EKS add-on. To add  Amazon EFS add-on to your cluster, see [Creating EFS add-on](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/efs-csi.html).

Alternatively, if you want a self-managed installation of the Amazon EFS CSI driver, see [Installation on GitHub](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/blob/master/docs/README.md#installation).